# Is there a more touch friendly desktop environment?

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-environments, touchscreen

I have an acer aspire r7 , its a convertible laptop/tablet.

I am interested in running a UI which is more like ubuntu touch. I installed the 13.10 thinking it was going to be more touch friendly, but it is not.

Is there some desktop environment or window manager I can use that has a more touch friendly UI?

I'd like swiping, and scrolling to be more like android or windows 8 than like mouse driven interfaces.

Answer (score 9):

There are three touch enabled interfaces for Linux:

- [Ubuntu Touch](http://ubuntu.com/phone) (not yet officially released)
- [Plasma Active](http://www.plasma-active.org/)
- [Zenvoid Desktop](http://alone-in-the-light.zenvoid.org/2012/09/desktop-for-tablets-and-mobile-devices.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) obviously provides a solid tablet touch interface while being [easy to install](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwwH6xBn4mg).  Just install Lil' Debi and XServer XSDL to run Linux applications.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Android-x86 is another operating system, not an Ubuntu overlay.